# Why does my code not merge table 1 to the bottom of table 2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

```sql
SELECT * INTO "2020_to_2021_divvy_tripdata"
  FROM
  (MERGE [PortfolioDB].[dbo].['202008-divvy-tripdata$'] as "202008"
  USING [PortfolioDB].[dbo].['202007-divvy-tripdata$'] as "202007" on [202007].ride_id = [202008].ride_id
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES ([202008].*)
```

I want it to take the data from 202008 and merge it to 202007 so that the one table simply is merged to the bottom of the other, but it says Incorrect syntax near *. I have tried all my previous toolkits like changing square brackets combinations and such.

Both tables are formatted the same, with the column names matching.

I tried to emulate the code from [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/). Eventually, I will merge multiple months onto each other to create a full-year table.

Comment: I've never seen code like this.  What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm guessing sqlserver from the link in the question...

Comment: are you sure you want to merge data or append data instead?

Comment: Please tag the database. To get you started, what happens when you run `SELECT @@VERSION`? Note that there is no such thing as "the bottom" of a table. Records are returned in order of whatever you have in your `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT VALUES()` has two issues...

1. You should insert from `[202007]` (the source), not from `[202008]` (the destination)
2. You can't use `[202007].*`, you have to list all the columns individually

---

Then, you need an `OUTPUT` clause for the `MERGE` to make its data available to an outer query.

---

Here's a demo: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff596fa2947dd71c10cb23ae6653e39f)

Here's a potential re-write of your statement...

```
INSERT INTO
  "2020_to_2021_divvy_tripdata"
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  MERGE [PortfolioDB].[dbo].['202008-divvy-tripdata$'] as "202008"
  USING [PortfolioDB].[dbo].['202007-divvy-tripdata$'] as "202007"
     ON [202007].ride_id = [202008].ride_id
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES ([202007].x, [202007].y, [202007].z)
  OUTPUT
    inserted.*
)
  merge_inserted
```